# Crystal Reports 2016 Formula Syntax

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports.
I have a DB where the Memory Column is being reported in KB.
I created a report for my IT director in which he wants that field to be reporting the memory in GB.
I tried this formula (based on book I purchased titled 'Beginner's Guide to Crystal Reports 2016')

```
IF {tblDts.Memory} = "" THEN "N/A" ELSE {tblDts.Memory}*0.4256
```

The error I get is

> A number, or currency amount is required here

and it highlights the `{tblDts.Memory}` after my `ELSE` statement.

That field in the database only has numeric values (btw - 0.4256 is the decimal format for 10240, I tried a division statement with the same results so I figured I try a multiplication statement).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I am going about creating the formula incorrectly? I select the data field in details and right-click on it, select Format Field. I then select the Common tab and click on the x-2 icon towards the right of Display String. Could that be my issue?

Answer (score 1):

In a conditional statement both `IF` and `ELSE` should return same datatype else there will be these kind of errors reported.

Here for IF you are returning string and for ELSE you are returning Number hence the error.

Suggested would be return `0` in case of IF and your calculation in ELSE

```
IF {tblDts.Memory} = "" 
THEN 0
ELSE {tblDts.Memory}*0.4256
```

Edit--------------------------------------------------

```
if IsNumber({tblDts.Memory})
then 
(
ToNumber({tblDts.Memory})*0.4256
)
else
0
```

Comment: I tried the formula and still get the same error of 'A number, or currency amount is required here' where {tblDts.Memory} is highlighted........maybe Crystal Reports is mad at me....lol

Comment: Can you post changed formula

Comment: Siva, I copied and pasted the formula you had posted in comments above. I wish I had the ability to attach a screen shot of what I am looking at and the error that pops up.

Comment: I have tried to take the IF THEN statement out completely just to see if I could get the calculation to work and still get the same error that it needs 'A number, or currency amount is required here'......could the error be that I am not using a decimal output on this field?

Comment: @Szmooz what is the datatype of `{tblDts.Memory}`? if it is string then change it. Check my edited answer.. for new formula